# Grouping and navigation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to group a set a range of cells with diffrent functions (formulas, drop-downs and formatting) and make them easier to navigate with the arrow keys?

**Example:**

Cells `G2`, `H2`, `I2` & `J2` represent a parameter of a data set.  I would like to be able to use the <kbd>→</kbd> key to navigate my parameters; but as opposed to pushing the arrow key 4 times, I would like to push the arrow key **once** and have it be at `K2` to speed up data entry.

Essentially bypassing the 3 cells to the right of the data row.  It is important that this doesn't mess with formatting or formulas for my intentions of use.

Comment: Do the cells `G2, H2, I2, J2` have to be visible? Otherwise you could _hide_, or what I personally prefer, _group_ the columns and then hide them. This would allow you to only press the right arrow key once.

Comment: You could insert an empty column between each parameter and use `CTRL` + arrow to navigate

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a consistent skip forward 4 columns, then you could just make a macro hotkey that skips that for you.

Just open in the Visual Basic editor and type:

Sub Macro1()

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
```

End Sub

Where the numbers in the parenthesis represent where you want to skip to. Then click the macros selection button and open the options to assign a hotkey for it (just make sure to not use a hotkey that is already in use, like ctrl+b for bold).